# How to get values of method's parameters?

Tags: java, methods, aspectj

I have the aspect:

```
public aspect TestAspect {
    pointcut publicMethodExecuted(): execution(public !static * *(..));

    int around() : publicMethodExecuted() {
        //I need parameters values here
        //to write their to log

        int original_return_value = proceed();
        return original_return_value * 100;
    }
}
```

How to get parameters the method was called with? I need to write their to log file.

I'm most interested in a native `AspectJ`-way, not using reflection.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry If I misunderstood but this should bring the parameters

```
Object[] args = thisJoinPoint.getArgs();
```

Comment: No, your understood the question perfectly correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can access the join point with `thisJoinPoint` inside your aspect.

You can access your parameters with `thisJoinPoint.getArgs()`.

Additionally you can access the signature of your method call with `thisJoinPointStaticPart`.

E.g. you can access the method name with `thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSignature().getName()`.

For further information please use the documentation of [JoinPoint](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/runtime-api/org/aspectj/lang/JoinPoint.html) and [JoinPoint.StaticPart](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/runtime-api/org/aspectj/lang/JoinPoint.StaticPart.html).